# MQQueueManager - Get Oldest Message in Queue

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I am using the IBM Supplied MQQueueManager via .Net to make various calls into our MQ Server / Queue.  I was wondering what method, if any, I could use to get that information? I have looked through the methods and nothing stands out.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  I am hoping to get the oldest message and at what time it was enqueued.

I know that MQSC Has this command which would be great to use if available in MQQueueManager:

Oldest message age - The age, in seconds, of the oldest message on the queue - **MSGAGE**

Thanks,

Scarpacci

Answer (score 1):

As you know we call it a `Queue`. Queue means **`FIFO`**(First in-First out). And FIFO means that by default when you issue an MQGET, you will get the oldest message(which came to queue before all others). If your requirement would have been to get the latest message in the queue then you would need some effort using BROWSE_NEXT MQGMO.

For getting Queue Status, you would need PCF. There are lot of examples available for PCF.
Check [**`this`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067657/getting-mq-queue-statistics-in-java) answer for instance.

Comment: If message delivery sequence (MSGDLVSQ) is set to PRIORITY then the first message delivered will not be the oldest message in a queue. Message with highest priority will be delivered first. PCF support (which is undocumented) in MQ .NET is not same as MQ Java.