# MQ Queue identification

Tags: queue, ibm-mq

I am trying to write a queue monitoring script for MQ. I want to identify the model queues and avoid them. Is there a way to identify the model queues and user created queue. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Model queues will have queue type as `MQQT_MODEL`. You can query the queue attributes and filter out model queues using the queue type.

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9067657/getting-mq-queue-statistics-in-java) shows how to query queue attributes using PCF Java classes.